# Compute a Jacobian matrix from scratch in Python

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, derivative, softmax

I'm trying to implement the derivative matrix of softmax function (Jacobian matrix of Softmax).

I know mathematically the derivative of Softmax(Xi) with respect to Xj is:

[image]

where the red delta is a Kronecker delta.

So far what I have implemented is:

```
def softmax_grad(s):
    # input s is softmax value of the original input x. Its shape is (1,n) 
    # e.i. s = np.array([0.3,0.7]), x = np.array([0,1])

    # make the matrix whose size is n^2.
    jacobian_m = np.diag(s)

    for i in range(len(jacobian_m)):
        for j in range(len(jacobian_m)):
            if i == j:
                jacobian_m[i][j] = s[i] * (1-s[i])
            else: 
                jacobian_m[i][j] = -s[i]*s[j]
    return jacobian_m
```

When I test:

```
In [95]: x
Out[95]: array([1, 2])

In [96]: softmax(x)
Out[96]: array([ 0.26894142,  0.73105858])

In [97]: softmax_grad(softmax(x))
Out[97]: 
array([[ 0.19661193, -0.19661193],
       [-0.19661193,  0.19661193]])
```

How do you guys implement Jacobian? I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this. Any reference to website/tutorial would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can vectorize `softmax_grad` like the following;

```
soft_max = softmax(x)
​
# reshape softmax to 2d so np.dot gives matrix multiplication
def softmax_grad(softmax):
    s = softmax.reshape(-1,1)
    return np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T)

softmax_grad(soft_max)

#array([[ 0.19661193, -0.19661193],
#       [-0.19661193,  0.19661193]])
```

---

*Details*: `sigma(j) * delta(ij)` is a diagonal matrix with `sigma(j)` as diagonal elements which you can create with `np.diagflat(s)`; `sigma(j) * sigma(i)` is a matrix multiplication (or outer product) of the softmax which can be calculated using `np.dot`:

Answer (score 0):

I've been tinkering with exactly this and this is what I've come up with. Maybe you'll find it useful. I think it's more explicit than the solution provided by Psidom.

```
def softmax_grad(probs):
    n_elements = probs.shape[0]
    jacobian = probs[:, np.newaxis] * (np.eye(n_elements) - probs[np.newaxis, :])
    return jacobian
```

Comment: this seems to have an error, you expand the wrong dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version which is easier to read than the accepted answer, and it assumes the input probabilities are (rows, n) instead of (1, n).

```
def softmax_grad(probs):
   # probs has shape (rows, n)
   # output has shape (rows, n, n) giving the jacobian for each row of probabilities
   eye = np.eye(probs.shape[-1])
   return probs[:, None, :] * (eye[None, :, :] - probs[:, :, None])
```